# Rudin: Union of countable sets

Tags: real-analysis

In Theorem 2.12 in Rudin, he proves that the countably infinite union of countably infinite sets is countable. I want to use the fact that the countably infinite union of $n$ countably sets (particularly $n = 2$) countable sets is countable in order to solve an exercise. The solution to the problem draws on this theorem to conclude that the union of two countable sets is countable. It does not seem to me that this works, but rather it requires another proof. The proofs I have seen that the union of two countable sets are countable are quite complicated, also, so this does not seem like a trivial extension of this theorem from Rudin.

Am I correct that an additional proof is needed, or does the result somehow folow from Rudin's theorem?

As an additional comment, would I be correct that any proof of countability involving a "diagonalization" argument is not as rigorous as, say, a proof involving sequences or an explicit bijection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows from Rudin's theorem, in several ways. You modify the proof a bit and do another diagonalisation argument, or if $A,B$ are countable, then you put $A_1:= A, A_2:= B$ and you take countable sets $A_3, A_4, \dots$. Then we have

$$A \cup B \subseteq  A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup \dots$$

and by Rudin's theorem, the latter is countable, so $A\cup B$ as well.

Alternatively, if $A$ and $B$ are countable and we write the elements of $A$ in a sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ and the elements of $B$ in a sequence $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$. Then you consider the sequence

$$a_1, b_1, a_2, b_2, a_3, b_3, \dots$$

and this gives a surjection $\mathbb{N} \to A \cup B$. Thus $|A \cup B| \leq |\mathbb{N}|$.

Comment: One could also just set $A_k := A$ for $k \ge 3$ and wouldn't need the last argument.

Comment: Yes, that works as well.

Comment: Is the third argument that we can identity $A \cup B$ with an infinite subset of a countable set, which must be countable by a past theorem? (Thank you also for this exceptional answer: this was extremely helpful.)

Comment: If we have a surjection $A\to B$, then we have $|B| \leq |A|$. Didn't Rudin prove or mention this? Intuitively, you can see this is true because every element of $B$ is attained, we must have more elements in $A$. Alternatively, the existence of a surjection $A \to B$ is equivalent with the existence of an injection $B \to A$ and then one can view $B$ as a subset of $A$, so $|B| \leq |A|$.

Comment: Thank you! This now makes sense.